# Why aren't my NSMutableArray objects being added to the UITableView straight away?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray with objects within it and I use the following code to add/remove objects from the UITableView. It works but only after closing and relaunching the app, not straight away. Why is this? Here is my code (maincelltext is the title in the cell and subtitlecelltext is the subtitle):

```
maincelltext = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
subtitlecelltext = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[maincelltext addObject:@"TITLE"];
[subtitlecelltext addObject:@"SUBTITLE TEST"];
```

EDIT: Here is my UITableView code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaBold" size:16.0];

cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES; 
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 1;

// Configure the cell.
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"warning.png"];
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 12.0, 12.0);
CGImageRef croppedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([cellImage CGImage], CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,cellImage.size.width,cellImage.size.height));
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cropRect];
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImage]]; 
CGImageRelease(croppedImage);
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];

cell.imageView.image = cellImage;

NSString *subjectString = [maincelltext objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

cell.textLabel.text = subjectString;

NSString *subtitle = [subtitlecelltext objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;

if(maincelltext.count == 0){

    NSString *notabledata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Dates Set"];
    [maincelltext addObject:notabledata];

}

return cell;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you please post some more details. This question is unusable like this

Comment: This is not enough to understand your question, post more code. Morevover in this way you're not adding/removing elements from the table but just from the array.

Comment: Have you try just to call [yourTable reloadData]; after entering new objects in the array?

Comment: See the answer below and my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell the UITableView that it needs to insert the rows.  First determine the index in the array the new object(s) are now at, then tell the UITableView to insert the rows like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPathOfNewObject=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: newObjectIndex section:0];
NSArray *indexPathArray=[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPathOfNewObject];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
// Note that UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic is for iOS5 only.
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

by using this method, you will get the cool animation effect on the tableView.

Alternatively, you could just call [self.tableView reloadData] and it will just reload all the data.

Good luck!

Comment: Right after adding the objects to you arrays. that way you have the indexes on hand.

Comment: Says: "file://localhost/Users/ReddexDesign/PixelBit%20Apps/School%20VLE%20Business/School%20VLE%20Business/ViewController.m: error: Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'newObjectIndex'"

Comment: The newObjectIndex is the new index of the objects you have added to the array.  That is something that you will have to figure out and provide.  This is just sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a `[myTableView reloadData];` after you did an `[myArray addObject:myObject];` and you should be fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, still nothing happens :'(